# Displaying a Facebook user's sex and others

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I'm starting an application in Facebook, and I'm having problems to get some user information.

The information I can't get is the following:

```
hometown_location
current_location
work
```

Here is my code:

```
<?php
    $app_id = "";
    $app_secret = "";
    $my_url = "";

    session_start();
    $code = $_REQUEST["code"];

    if(empty($code)) {
        $_SESSION['state'] = md5(uniqid(rand(), TRUE)); //CSRF protection
        $dialog_url = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id="
          . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url) . "&scope=email,offline_access,publish_stream,user_birthday,user_education_history,user_location,user_hometown,user_relationships,user_relationship_details,user_work_history&state="
          . $_SESSION['state'];

        echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $dialog_url . "'</script>");
    }

    if($_REQUEST['state'] == $_SESSION['state']) {
        $token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?"
          . "client_id=" . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url)
          . "&client_secret=" . $app_secret . "&code=" . $code;

        $response = file_get_contents($token_url);
        $params = null;
        parse_str($response, $params);

        $graph_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token="
          . $params['access_token'];

        $user = json_decode(file_get_contents($graph_url));
        echo("Hello " . $user->name.'<br />');
        echo("id " . $user->id.'<br />');
        echo("mail  " . $user->email.'<br />');
        echo("birthday  " . $user->birthday.'<br />');
        echo("sex  " . $user->sex.'<br />');
        echo("hometown_location  " . $user->hometown_location.'<br />');
        echo("relationship_status  " . $user->relationship_status.'<br />');
        echo("current_location  " . $user->current_location.'<br />');
        echo("education  " . $user->education.'<br />');
        echo("work  " . $user->work.'<br />');
    }
    else {
    }
 ?>
```

I got the sex with "gender", but I can't figure out the others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The properties you want are `hometown` and `location`. Hometown requires the user to grant `user_hometown` and Location requires the user to grant `user_location` permissions to your app:

```
  ....
  "username": "alienwebguy", 
  "hometown": {
    "id": "112276852118956", 
    "name": "Maple Grove, Minnesota"
  }, 
  "location": {
    "id": "102825596420583", 
    "name": "Antioch, California"
  }, 
  ....
```

Per the [Open Graph "User" API docs](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/):

```
hometown    The user's hometown       user_hometown or friends_hometown   object containing name and id
location    The user's current city   user_location or friends_location   object containing name and id
```

Comment: tried with user_hometown and user_location but i just get blank response. If you check the user actually granted user_hometown and user_location. Im almost there but im just getting an empty echo with those two. Thanks

Comment: im feeling kind of stupid... it was just $user->hometown->id and $user->location->id. Thanks!